# Qt5 QML how to prevent Slider rogue initial value

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I have a `Slider`. `value` reads from my persistent value and `onValueChanged` writes to it. However, setting `minimumValue` to, say 1, calls `onValueChanged` before the initial access of my `value`. This causes my persistent value to be overwritten to 1 always.

eg

```
Slider
{
    stepSize: 1
    minimumValue: 1  // this happens before `value` regarless of order here
    maximumValue: 5
    value: myPersistentValue
    onValueChanged:
    {
        // gets called *before* myPersistentValue is accessed and overwrites it!
        myPersistentValue = value
    }
}
```

Is there some way to prevent this or test for readiness somehow?

thanks.

Comment: This is a dependency loop, and is invalid. You must do something else, this won't ever work. It only happens to work because the QML engine breaks dependency loops for you as a last resort to prevent a crash/frozen GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way of solving this is using a bool to control whether the `Slider` is completed or not so `myPersistentValue` will be changed only when `Slider` is already completed.

Something like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow {
    id: rootWindow
    objectName: "window"
    visible: true
    width: 200
    height: 200

    property int myPersistentValue: 5

    Slider
    {
        id: mySlider
        stepSize: 1
        minimumValue: 1
        maximumValue: 5
        value: myPersistentValue

        property bool completed: false

        onValueChanged:
        {
            console.log("slider - onValueChanged: " + myPersistentValue +
                        " value: " + value )

            if (completed) {
                console.log("slider - onValueChanged & completed: " + myPersistentValue +
                            " value: " + value )
                myPersistentValue = value
            }
        }

        Component.onCompleted: {
           console.log("Slider completed!")
           completed = true
        }
    }


    Button
    {
        y: 50
        text: "click me!"
        onClicked: {
            myPersistentValue = myPersistentValue - 1
            console.log("button - onClicked: " + myPersistentValue)
        }
    }
}
```

I would be great if QML standard components had this information, but I'm afraid not.

By the way, surprisingly, if you set `minimumValue` less than or equal to 0, the behaviour is different. During the initialization, `onValueChanged` is only called once and `value` is equal to `myPersistentValue`.

Comment: Your answer is the simplest way ive found to fix this. I feels it's a bit bogus to have to have a property to ensure the slider is ready. thanks for your help.

Comment: To save a few lines of code you could use `readonly property bool completed: Component.completed`